# Why does diff fail when invoked from a Makefile?

Tags: make, diff, patch

Narrow-down of a patch problem I am trying to troubleshoot:
Only two files, each with a size of 1 byte:

- file `a` (containing `'a'`)
- file `b` (containing `'b'`) and

Goal is to make and then apply a patch that will change the value of `'b'` to `'a'`. Contents of Makefile are:

```
patch:
        diff -u b a > b2a.patch
        patch -o b.corrected b < b2a.patch
        diff a b.corrected

clean:
        rm -f b2a.patch b.corrected
```

Given the above, `make` fails with the following output:

```
$ make
diff -u b a > b2a.patch
make: *** [patch] Error 1
```

If, however, I execute the commands in the Makefile one after the other on the bash shell, there is no problem at all.

Comment: what's the `exit code` of `diff` when you run it manually?

Comment: @umlaute it's 1

Comment: @umlaute ok so replacing 'diff' with '-diff' fixes it - it was a Makefile thing

Comment: I'm at a loss on why you want to make and then immediately apply the patch... e.g., why not just use `cp`? Since that doesn't really make much sense, I assume this is a simplified test case.

Comment: @derobert your assumption is correct. I note as much at the beginning of my post ("Narrow-down ..")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make assumes that an exit code of 0 means success, anything else means failure. This is the standard convention used by almost all command-line tools.

Unfortunately, `diff` is not one of those. Checking the GNU diff info page, and also the [Single Unix Specification "diff" entry](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html), 0 means no differences found, 1 means differences found, and ≥2 means error.

You can tell Make to ignore the exit status entirely by prefixing the command with a hyphen, as you did in your comment, but this will ignore actual errors—probably not what you want. Instead, you can:

```
patch:
        diff -u b a > b2a.patch; [ $$? -eq 1 ]
        patch -o b.corrected b < b2a.patch
        diff a b.corrected; [ $$? -eq 1 ]
```

Note the `; [ $$? -eq 1 ]` bit I've added to the end of the two diff lines. You can use `; test $$? -eq 1` as well, of course. The `$?` shell variable is `$$?` due to normal Makefile escaping conventions. Note this also rejects exit status 0 (no differences), which is probably what you want.

BTW: it appears this really ought to be:

```
patch: b.corrected
        diff …
b.corrected: b2a.patch
        patch …
b2a.patch: a b
        diff …
```

so that modifications of a and b get picked up, and the files regenerated correctly.

Comment: @Bananguin Thanks for the edit, that probably is true. I'm not entirely sure what OP is trying accomplish...

Comment: actually i just felt bad because your version was not wrong, just one corner too much for me to handle before dinner. still, it's more spelled out now :D

Comment: The Unix convention for return codes is a bit broader than “0 for success, >0 for failure”. For commands that return a boolean result, the convention is “0 for yes, 1 for no, >1 for failure”. `diff` is an example of this, as are `grep`, `test`, …

Comment: @Gilles Well, `diff` would ask "are these files different?"... Arguably, diff is backwards. But I guess both it and `cmp` both return 0 for match, 1 for differ.

Comment: @derobert `diff` and `cmp` ask “are these files identical?”

Comment: @Gilles I went through the Single Unix Spec, and other weird exit codes are `expr` (0: non-null, non-zero; 1: null, zero; 2: syntax; 3+: other error), `false` (duh), `grep` (0: match, 1: no match; 2+: error), `localedef` (0: ok, 1: warnings, 2+ various errors), `mail -e` (0: present, 1: not present); `mesg` (0=y 1=n, but GNU always returns 0…), `sort -c` (0: sorted, 1: not); `test` (0: true, 1: false, 2+: err); maybe `tty` (1: not a terminal); and `what` (SCCS, match/no-match). So the "are they different" convention is two commands; Yes/no is maybe 7 commands, out of 160. ~95% follow !0 = err